# Apple push notification for multiple device token issue

Tags: c#, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send push notification for single device token it works but when I am trying to send for multiple device token its does not send

working code for single device

```
String deviceId = "devicetoken"

 for (int i = 0; i < xTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                chkToken = xTable.Rows[i]["token"].ToString() ;
                apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
                {

                    DeviceToken = deviceId,
                    Payload = JObject.Parse(json)
                    //Payload = JObject.Parse("{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + "Hi,, This Is a Sample Push Notification For IPhone.." + "\",\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}")
                });
            }
```

not working code for multiple device token

```
String chkToken = "";
            DataTable xTable = getTokensDtMobile;
            for (int i = 0; i < xTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                chkToken = xTable.Rows[i]["token"].ToString() ;
                apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
                {

                    DeviceToken = chkToken,
                    Payload = JObject.Parse(json)
                    //Payload = JObject.Parse("{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + "Hi,, This Is a Sample Push Notification For IPhone.." + "\",\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}")
                });
            }
```

Comment: Did you make sure that device tokens are valid and are registered by actual devices? As far as I know, simulators can't receive push notifications from APNS.

Comment: yes actually similar type of issue what that, few tokens were blank, I just found it thank for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Code was right but only issue was that there was few device token were blank in database. I have added condition. if token is = "" then it will submit for push notification.